# Is it possible to enable smart quotes in a text label iOS 6 or 7?

Tags: ios7, ios6

I would like to enable smart quotes (quotation marks that are curvy and face towards each other instead of straight vertical lines) in an iOS app in UITextField and UITextView, is this possible?

Comment: You need to clarify what you want.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell it's not possible. Neither UITextField nor UITextView have that option. It's difficult to even do it yourself (in post-processing, for example), because unlike on Mac OS -- where NSSpellChecker will give you the correct smart quotes to use -- on iOS there's no such thing. The closest I've found (though I'm still looking) is the quote characters from NSLocale. For example,

```
NSString *leftQuoteString = [[NSLocale currentLocale] objectForKey:NSLocaleQuotationBeginDelimiterKey]];
```